# How to draw text at runtime

Tags: c#, graphics, text, paint, draw

Basically, Im making a paint application very similar to MSPaint.
The idea is that, that the the user clicks anywhere on the form and should be able to write text in a control. And then following that, that text should be displayed in g.drawstring graphic method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't want to do the whole thing for you, but here is a basic outline of one way to accomplish the goals you outline. This is not necessarily the best way, but it should get you started and will introduce you to a number of WinForms concepts.

**Writing the text**
Create a [`Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx) and add a [`TextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx) control to it. Make sure it is hidden by default. Override the [`OnMouseClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onmouseclick.aspx) method of your [`Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx) and add code that checks if the [`TextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx) is visible and if not, shows it and puts focus to it for the user to enter their text. If the [`TextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx) is already visible, the code should hide it and create a new [`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx) in its place that shows the text (see below for details of that [`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx)).

Also add an event handler to the [`TextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx) so that if the user hits Esc, it cancels the edit and if they hit Enter, the text is accepted and the [`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx) is created.

**Displaying the text**
Create a [`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx) and make sure that the [`UserPaint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles.aspx) and [`Opaque`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles.aspx) styles are set in its construction (see [`SetStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle.aspx) - you may also want to consider [`OptimizedDoubleBuffer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles.aspx) and [`AllPaintingInWmPaint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles.aspx) as this can reduce flickering though it does require extra paint code).

Override the [`OnPaint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e40ahaz.aspx) method in your [`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles.aspx) and implement the code for drawing the string (remember, you'll also need a way to set the text on the control).

**Conclusion**
If you hook all that up, you should have something that appears to meet your requirements. For further experimentation, consider how you could remove the need for the [`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx). Good luck and have fun!